# Looking for a micro USB to lightning cable

Tags: usb, microphones, cable

I am looking for a Micro USB to Lightning cable. (i.e. micro USB at one end, Lightning at the other end)

Any recommendations? I've checked out Amazon and Best Buy to no avail.

Required in order to hook up [this mic](https://apogeedigital.com/products/hypemic) to my iPhone.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there one in the microphone box?

Comment: Yes. It broke, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the linked site, in the accessories section, this cable appears to be the match:

https://apogeedigital.com/shop/2-meter-micro-b-to-lightning-cable-for-mic-plus

[image: USB to lightning cable]

Direct paste from link:

```
Compatible with MiC Plus, HypeMiC and Jam Plus
For connecting to iPad, iPhone or iPod with Lightning connector
```